# How can I remotely debug linux module using GDB?

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, gdb

I searched all over the internet but couldn't find proper steps to debug linux module remotely using gdb. I am tring qemu but facing many issues there. Is there any other tool that I can use or if not then can you provide me proper steps to debug linux module remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be that hard. From the [official kernel documentation](https://docs.kernel.org/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html) (don't search "all over the internet". Search the official documentation and you'll find less bad information):

1. Have a kernel that has `KGBD` enabled, and also make sure that during building the config option `CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS` is on. (Refer to documentation for CentOS on how to build a kernel package; that's the easiest way)

   - run `make scripts_gdb`
2. Copy that kernel (`vmlinux`) into your host system, so that it's easy to know the kernel symbols locally
3. Run the Linux distro of your choice in QEMU

   - with QEMU's GDB stub enabled, and listening on some port, i.e., run `qemu` with `-gdb tcp::$SOMEPORT`, where `$SOMEPORT` is the port number you want to use (should be > 1024, < 2¹⁶). **Alternatively**, run with `-s`, which is identical to `-gdb tcp::1234`.
   - Make sure that QEMU doesn't boot the machine instantly by supplying the `-S` option
4. on the host, run `gdb /path/to/the/kernel/vmlinux`
5. in `gdb`, attach to your QEMU stub: `target remote :$SOMEPORT`.
6. you can now run `continue` to boot the VM

Comment: Hii Marcus, to be clear I am looking for a way to debug linux driver remotely. For ex. Module is running on VM A and I want to debug that module from VM B through GDB? Do you know any way to do it?

Comment: exactly the method I described above. The module is part of the kernel space, so if you want to debug it, this is exactly what you need to do.